# View with @foreach

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this:

View:

```
@using Multitask.Regenboog.Medicijnverstrekking.Domain
@using Multitask.Regenboog.Medicijnverstrekking.WebApplication.ViewModels.FAQ
@model  FaqOverviewModel


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Support</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveFaq", "FAQ", FormMethod.Post))
{

    @*<table align="right" border="1">
            <tr>hallo</tr>
            <tr>hallo2</tr>

        </table>*@



    <p>
        <span class="fixedLabelWidth control-label col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-xl-2">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedCategoriedFaqId, "Kies een Categorie:")</span>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedCategoriedFaqId, Model.FAQCategorieItems, "Selecteer een Categorie")
        <br /><br />
        <span class="fixedLabelWidth control-label col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-xl-2">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmailBericht, "Kies een Onderwerp:")</span>
        @*<span class="fixedLabelWidth "></span><b> een onderwerp</b*@ <select name="Naam" id="FaqCategorie_Id"></select>


    </p>

    <p>
        <span class="fixedLabelWidth control-label col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-xl-2">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmailBericht, "Bericht:")</span>
        @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.EmailBericht)
    </p>

    <p>
        <span class="fixedLabelWidth control-label col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-xl-2">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.AfzenderNaam, "Afzender:")</span>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.AfzenderNaam)
    </p>

    <p>
        <span class="fixedLabelWidth control-label col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-xl-2">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.TelefoonNr, "Tel:")</span>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.TelefoonNr)
    </p>


    <p>

    <p>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Vraag)

        <input type="submit" value="Zoek" />
    </p>

<p>
    Zoek een vraag: @Html.TextBox("SearchString")
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</p>
 }



<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Last Name", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm, currentFilter=ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
        </th>
        <th>
            First Name
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Enrollment Date", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.DateSortParm, currentFilter=ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>


    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Vraag)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Antwoord)
            </td>

        </tr>
}

</table>
<br />
@*Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount

@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index",
    new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }))*@

@section scripts
{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/Form")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Bundles/Q")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Bundles/moment")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/Utils")



    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/Jquery-ui")


    <script type="text/javascript">

        function AddToCart(id) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Medicijnverstrekking/FAQ/SaveFaq/",
                data: { id: id },
                success: function () {
                    alert('Added');
                }
            });
        }


        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#SelectedCategoriedFaqId").change(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Medicijnverstrekking/FAQ/SubCategorie/",
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {
                        Categorieid: this.value
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        //  $('SelectedCategoriedFaqId').val('').remove();
                        //alert("Data retrieval successfull");
                        var items = "";
                        $('#FaqCategorie_Id').empty();
                        $.each(data, function (i, val) {
                            var opt = $("<option></option>")
                              .attr("value", val.Value)
                              .text(val.Text);
                            $('#FaqCategorie_Id').append(opt);
                        });

                    },
                    error: function (xhr) {
                        alert("Something seems Wrong");
                    }
                });

            });

        });

    </script>
}
```

But I get this error:

> foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Multitask.Regenboog.Medicijnverstrekking.WebApplication.ViewModels.FAQ.FaqOverviewModel' because 'Multitask.Regenboog.Medicijnverstrekking.WebApplication.ViewModels.FAQ.FaqOverviewModel' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'    c:\Projects\Multitask.Regenboog.Medicijnverstrekking-trunk\WebApplication\Views\FAQ\Index.cshtml    80  6   WebApplication (WebApplication\WebApplication)

Comment: That's because that type isn't a list and therefore the foreach can't process it

Comment: You are trying to iterate over your model but your model isn't a collection.

Comment: @savantKing can you post your FaqOverviewModel class so I can see the structure and also the class where your Vraag and Antwoord properties come from?

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Vraag)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Antwoord)
        </td>

    </tr>
}
```

and yet your FaqOverviewModel ViewModel is not something that implements IEnumerable (a List, etc).

Is `@foreach (var item in Model)` supposed to be `@foreach (var item in Model.SomeCollectionOfThings)`? (Where SomeCollectionOfThings is a `List` property of objects with `Vraag` and `Antwoord` properties)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@model FaqOverviewModel
...
...
@foreach (var item in IEnumerable<Model>) {
```

Comment: @savantKing, check my answer. Try it and see if it works

Comment: Thank you. But then I get this error: Error 7 'System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<TModel>.Model' is a 'property' but is used like a 'type' c:\Projects\Multitask.Regenboog.Medicijnverstrekking-trunk\WebApplication\Views\FAQ\Index.cshtml 80 38 WebApplication (WebApplication\WebApplication)

Comment: Sorry @savantKing, I thought that could fix the problem. I don't see how to fix it then